# Why do I get this Error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I would like to create a JSON file from the data from my database which has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "src": [
      [
        "(",
        "cnn"
      ],
      [...]
    ],
    "tgt": [
      [
        "pov",
        "video"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried to create the file that way:

```
data = []
data.append({})
data['scr'] = []
data['tgt'] = []

print(data)
```

But i get that error:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5733e311e47b> in <module>()
      1 data = []
      2 data.append({})
----> 3 data['scr'] = ""
      4 data['tgt'] = ""
      5 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

But if I change a little bit I get the right edition, except for the bracket that clasps everything.

```
data = {}
#data.append({})
data['scr'] = []
data['tgt'] = []

print(data)

output: {'scr': [], 'tgt': []}
```

How do I do this right?

Comment: Once you've created your `data` dictionary, `data_list = [data]`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, thank you. I copied the wrong sentence.  I didn't even recognize it.

Comment: I wish I spoke another language so well that **I** could make that mistake. :-)